# Can't seem to move an element

Tags: html, css

Hey I've stumbled onto something that seems quite simple and almost banal, but I can't just wrap my head around it.

So I've got a website and applied a bit of cascading stylesheet to it.

[image: This is what the top of website looks like]

This is the element I'm talking about on top of the website.

Quite simple really, but for some reason I can't seem to use margin, nor padding to influence the first line of text (#FFF white one). Or to be more specific, margin works, just not margin-top (nor negative bottom).

HTML looks something like this

```
<html>
...
<body>
 <div id = "header">
  <a href="#">I can't margin-top this</a>
  <h1>However it works on this</h1>
</div>
....
</body>
```

And the stylesheet like this.

[image: My stylesheet]

Now, as you may see, the first `<a>` should be on margin of 20px, however for some weird reason it seems immune to margin (and padding as well). The `<h1>` below is operational.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Last but not least, here's inspection of the `<a>` element

[image: The inspection of the <a> element]

Probably has a simple solution, but I went out of practice and I can't really figure out what's the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inline` element cannot take size or vertical `margin`/`padding`, give a `display:inline-block` to `<a>` and it will accept the `margin-top`

```
#header a {
display:inline-block;
/* + here your css rules */
}
```

Comment: Worked out. Thanks. Completely forgot about the fact inlines can't be moved.

Though out of curiosity, would you recommend doing this? (I know it will work, but it's more of a work-around around the issue. Wouldn't it be better to create a separate div, or maybe paragraph to force it into a block instead, rather than applying it as an inlineblock through CSS?)

What is the better "go-to"  design option?

Comment: @Rawrplus up to you wich display you want to give, any but inline turns it into a box. inline-block or block level. block is usefull if you want it to use all width avalaible and break line before and after itself